# how to merge all multidimensional array into an single array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

my code:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [15-3] => 1 )
[1] => Array ( [16-3] => 2 )
[2] => Array ( [15-4] => 3 )
[3] => Array ( [16-4] => 4 )
[4] => Array ( [15-3] => 11 )
[5] => Array ( [16-3] => 22 ) 
[6] => Array ( [15-4] => 33 ) 
[7] => Array ( [16-4] => 44 ) 
[8] => Array ( [15-3] => 111 ) 
[9] => Array ( [16-3] => 222 ) 
[10] => Array ( [15-4] => 333 ) 
[11] => Array ( [16-4] => 444 ) 
[12] => Array ( [15-3] => 1111 ) 
[13] => Array ( [16-3] => 2222 ) 
[14] => Array ( [15-4] => 3333 ) 
[15] => Array ( [16-4] => 4444 ) 
)
```

In above my data placed in array with in an array, inn that how can i merge all the values into one like an single array

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: You can't really, when you want to keep all the keys in the second array. Because it will overwrite eachother.

Comment: What keys do you want ?

Comment: Take a look at phps `array_merge()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Use `array_values()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Comment: $final_array=Array ( [15-3] => 1 [16-3] => 2 [15-4] => 3 [16-4] => 4 [15-3] => 11 [16-3] => 22 [15-4] => 33 [16-4] => 44 [15-3] => 111 [16-3] => 222 [15-4] => 333 [16-4] => 444 [15-3] => 1111 [16-3] => 2222 [15-4] => 3333 [16-4] => 4444)

Comment: Well you can't, because the keys are not unique.

Comment: It's your second question with this and you still can't have duplicate keys!

Answer (score 0):

Some confusion there in your question. I understand you need like this.

```
Array ( 
 [15-3] => 1
 [16-3] => 2 
 [15-4] => 3 
 ........
)
```

Then use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function in PHP

```
$inner_array = array_values($initial_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I add full code of your previous  question also but i change the key in to values:

```
$attri_ids_all=Array ("0" => "15-3" ,"1" => "16-3", "2" => "15-4" ,"3" => "16-4" ,"4" => "15-3" ,"5" => "16-3", "6" => "15-4" ,"7" => "16-4", "8" => "15-3", "9" => "16-3", "10" => "15-4", "11" => "16-4", "12" => "15-3", "13" => "16-3", "14" => "15-4", "15" => "16-4" ); 

$inventory_code_qty=Array ("0" => "1", "1" => "2", "2" => "3", "3" => "4" ,"4" => "11" ,"5" => "22" ,"6" => "33", "7" => "44", "8" => "111" ,"9" => "222" ,"10" => "333", "11" => "444" ,"12" => "1111", "13" => "2222", "14" => "3333", "15" => "4444" ); 


function foo($key, $val) {
   return $val;
}
$arrResult = array_map('foo', $attri_ids_all, $inventory_code_qty);

$arr1=array_values($attri_ids_all);
$arr2 = $arrResult;
echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_combine($arr2,$arr1));
echo "</pre>";
```